# German Umlaute ä, ö, ß, ... are not shown in PDF file

Tags: accents, characters, german

I have a problem writing German Umlaute like, ä, ö, ß, .... They show up as cryptical signs but not as Umlaute in the pdf- file. Here is my latex code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,german,fleqn,oneside‎]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman, german]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}        % Latin Modern
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    %T1 (Cork) encoding 
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}       % extensive support for hypertext in LaTeX.
\usepackage{textcomp}        % Zusätzliche Symbole (Text Companion font extension)
\usepackage{mathcomp}       % Symbole
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc} % wegen deutschen Umlauten
\usepackage{listings}        % Code



\linespread{1.3}
%%Absatzeinrückungen festlegen - keinen Einschub am Anfang, vertikaler Abstand
 \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\mathindent}{20pt}
 \setlength{\parskip}\medskipamount % besser als explizite Angabe in pt
 \hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand\abs[1]{\left\lvert#1\right\rvert}
\newcommand\ceil[1]{\left\lceil#1\right\rceil}
\newcommand\floor[1]{\left\lfloor#1\right\rfloor}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left| \left| #1 \right| \right|}
\newcommand{\op}[0]{\operatorname{Op}}

\title{Expose}
\author{Bianca Drefahl} 
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\begin{table*}
    %\centering
        \begin{tabular}{p{8.8cm} p{9cm}}
            \bfseries Bianca Drefahl & \bfseries Promotion in Philisophie \\
            \bfseries Expose  & \bfseries Immatrikulationsnummer 3479924   \\
        \end{tabular}
\end{table*}


\end{center}


\section{Zur Rolle des Zufalls in "MIM of De doorstoken globe" van A.F.Th. van der Heijden}

\subsection{Erzählstruktur und - aufbau}

Das Buch beginnt mit einer dem Haupttext vorangestellten Bemerkung, dass seitens des Autors alles moegliche unternommen wurde, um sicherzustellen, dass keine Tiere in dem Buch gequaelt werden. Denn Mulisch hat hiergegen eine grosse Abneigung.Dies erweist sich aber als nicht gaenzlich umsetzbar. Danach beginnt der eigentlich Roman.

Das Werk ist in drei Kapitel unterteilt

\begin{enumerate}
    \item De doorstoken globe
    \item Edelweiss 
    \item Braille voor het oog
\end{enumerate} 


Die drei Kapitel der MIM-Novelle  unterteilen sich wiederum in nummerierte Unterkapitel. So hat das erste Kapitel sieben Unterkapitel, das zweite Kapitel dreizehn Unterkapitel und das dritte Kapitel wieder sieben Unterkapitel. Die Laenge der Kapitel und Unterkapitel variieren stark.

Die Struktur und der Inhalt des Romans \glqq MIM \grqq von van der Heijden weist transtexturelle Parallelen zu der mehr als 2400 Jahre alten griechischen Tragoedie \glqq Oedipus der Tyrann \grqq von Sophokoles auf. Gemaess der antiken Aufbauweise von klassischen Theaterstuecken gibt es eine Einheit von Zeit, Ort und Handlung. Die Hauptfigur Movo erfaehrt in \glqq MIM \grqq eine aehnliche Fuegung von Geschehnissen wie Oedipus. Beide werden nach der Geburt von den Eltern verstossen, wachsen bei Adoptiveltern auf, werden Anfuehrer der Gegenpartei, toeten den leiblichen Vater und ehelichen die leibliche Mutter.

Die Paralellelen zwischen \glqq MIM \grqq und \glqq Oedipus \grqq sind in deren zugrundelegender Struktur und deren elementaren Handlungsverlauf erkennbar. In Details und Kontexten hingegen variieren beide Werke voneinander: Namen, Orte, Motive, Taetigkeiten unterscheiden sich. In van der Heijdens Roman \glqq MIM" ist die niederlaendische Stadt Rotterdam Ort der Handlung ist und die Geschehnisse spielen sich in der Jetztzeit im Verlauf des Tages des 25. Septembers 1999 ab.

Aus einem antiken Theaterstueck mit stringenter Struktur ist ein postmoderner Roman mit nichtlinearer Struktur und unterschiedlichen Erzaehlperspektiven geworden.Allgemein gibt es einen Ich-Erzaehler und abwechseln dazu wird in einigen Passagen in dem Roman speziell aus der persoenlichen Perspektive von Movo (der Hauptfiguur) oder von Zora (dessen Ehefrau) erzaehlt.


\subsection{Zusammenfassung des Inhalts}

\subsubsection{Februar 1973}

Im Jahr 1973 hat Zora mit fuenfzehn Jahren zusammen mit ihrer Freundin Ulbine einen Pornofilm gedreht. Der Film heisst  \glqq Edelweiss \grqq  und ist eine Art pornografischer Heidi-Film. Zora is Edelweiss, die bei Heidi, gespielt durch Ulbine, logiert. Beide haben sexuelle Spielchen mit dem Jungen Peter, gespielt durch T.   







 \cite[Siehe Seite 1]{Anonym:eigenwertproblem}


\cite[angelehnt an Seite 1]{Anonym:eigenwertproblem}














































% Literaturliste soll im Inhaltsverzeichnis auftauchen
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Literatur}



\bibliography{literatur1}
\bibliographystyle{plain}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Very possibly your file is not encoded in `ansinew`, but using `utf8`. Is the output like in [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WFAho.png)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your example code, while rather long, does not appear to contain *any* instances of `ö`, `ü`, or `ß` and only one instance of `ä` (other than in comments, which don't matter). It also appears to be the case that your file's input encoding is not `ansinew` but, rather, `utf8`.

Comment: The Output of Umlaute looks indead like in your picture. But I think, I am using ansinew and not utf8.

Comment: You are just starting, right? http://www.golatex.de/minimale-vorlagen-vs-maximale-vorlagen-t10780.html

Comment: Looking at the bit of text from your work i would say: Most of the stuff you have there isn't needed and you don't know what it does.

Answer (score 5):

First, I haven't seen umlauts at a first glance in the MWE, which contains the ASCII replacements, e.g. "fuenfzehn" instead of "fünfzehn".

"Cryptic signs" can mean that the real encoding is UTF-8, but the MWE uses "ansinew". Then switching to

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

should solve the issue. If you are unsure about the right input encoding, then package `selinput` can be used, see its documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have files in different encodings, or that might be re-encoded, you might use the `selinput` package in place of `inputenc`.  It was designed for this situation, and will work regardless of what encoding the file is in.

The manual suggests the commands

```
\usepackage{selinput}
\SelectInputMappings{
  adieresis={ä},
  germandbls={ß},
  Euro={€},
}
```

If you can, however, I would save everything in UTF-8.